# How to find highlighted text in Microsoft Office Word or Excel document

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

Is there any possibility to find a highlighted text in Microsoft office documents?
Let's imagine that I have a file and I need all the highlighted text of all colors to be hidden. 
So after the processing I will get a file and the highlighted in the beginning text will be hidden.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Depends on the document format, and on how much time you are willing to put into the processing program.

Comment: the format is xls or xlsx or doc and docx. There are no any requirenments for the time

Comment: In 'xls' or 'xlsx', you can do an Excel macro to do the job.  For Word, you would probably have to parse the source code of the text in order to do it.

Comment: When it comes to such a requirement, the first thing to do is trying the same in the involved applications. Then you would see that `Microsoft Word` is able to hide text using a font format. `Microsoft Excel` is able to hide cell values using a cell number format. Next do a search how to find "highlighted" text in both of the file types and then how to apply the needed formats using `Java`. Now you have approaches how to do. Try something and come back with a concrete question if you are stuck. As it is now, this question is to broad and shows that you have not done own efforts.

Comment: your right, I didn't try but I need just an approach because I didn't word with Word files earlier. Will try to find anything connected with parsing of Word documents..

Answer (score 1):

(I was going to comment but I can't because I don't have enough reputation)
I found that you may be able to browse the code to find a Color Sensor (like [this one](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/lejos/nxt/ColorSensor.html)). Since you know the color of the box, you could execute a `Java.lang.Robot` command to hide the cell if you find it.

---

Comment: So, how do you imagine the OP doing this?  Just buying a robot with 100's of sensors, and every time she scrolls have the robot execute Java commands???  I would vote down, but don't want to hurt your reputation more.

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry, it was going to be a comment (I'm new here). I think you might be a little mistaken on the meaning of robots - I am referring to the Java import, which moves your mouse, not an actual physical robot. Sorry!

Comment: You don't need the @Alex when replying to me...  In either case, the ColorSensor class can only be used with physical robots (which have physical color sensors installed)(e.g. Lego NXT robot).  That's why your answer doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Oh. Maybe she could download a color senser import on Java... I thought it was a color senser for java (and not NXT).

Comment: That's false.  The page clearly says, "This driver provides access to the LEGO Color sensor."

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. I searched up "Color Sensor for Java", and found that. Look, I didn't mean to give a link of an NXT robot, I just didn't read it fully. It isn't complete, it was meant to try to be a helpful comment. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150437/discussion-between-shreyas-shridharan-and-alex).